# Reliably Compressing the image horizontally to 1 column of pixels with 100% thresholding

Tags: imagemagick

I am looking for a way to reliably compress an image horizontally to one column of pixels in such manner that:

- any row of pixels that is not composed of all-white pixels becomes a  black pixel in the resulting column
- any row of pixels that is composed of all-white pixels becomes a white pixel in the resulting column

Below is the raw input image:
[image: Raw image input]

The best I could do is with this code:

```
magick convert input.png -alpha off -threshold 99% -scale 1x75! -threshold 99% output.png
```

However the output is imperfect, because there are gaps in the column of pixels:

[image]

...and my desired output is:

[image]

Comment: use -morphology open rectangle:1x5 at the end of your command to fill the gaps.  Change 5 to whatever is the largest gap amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `magick convert ...` because it gives you old v6 behaviour which is normally not a good idea now that we have v7. I am suggesting you use `magick` rather than `magick convert`.

So, in summary, just use:

- `magick INPUT operations OUTPUT` - in place of v6 `convert INPUT operations OUTPUT`
- `magick identify ...`
- `magick compare ...`
- `magick compose ...`

---

As regards your question, after the initial threshold:

```
magick logo.png -alpha off -threshold 99% result.png
```

you are left with this:

[image]

and the problem is that just 2 black pixels in a row of 1278 pixels doesn't amount to much and they disappear in the noise. My suggestion would be to run a statistical minimum over an area of 200x1 pixels. That means any pixel within 200 pixels left and right of any black pixel becomes black like this:

```
magick logo.png -alpha off -threshold 99% -statistic minimum 200x1 result.png
```

[image]

Now there are lots of black ones to show up adequately significantly in the final image:

```
magick logo.png -alpha off -threshold 99% -statistic minimum 200x1 -scale 1x\! -threshold 99% result.png
```

[image]

---

Rather than the hard-coded 200, you could make it, say, 1/8 the width of the image to be adaptive to the width of the image and give a reasonable performance (making the area wider will slow the processing down):

```
magick logo.png -alpha off -threshold 99% -statistic minimum "%[fx:int(w/8)]x1"  result.png
```

Comment: I knew that "...just 2 black pixels in a row of 1278 pixels doesn't amount to much and they disappear in the noise" but I did not know how to make the `-scale` use the `minimum` algorithm instead of the `average`,...or whatever `-scale` uses.  I made my own utility in C that iterates over the entire image using two nested `for` loops, one for rows and one for columns, and it `exits` the inner "column" `for` loop as soon as it encounters a non-white pixel.  I wanted to do the same in I.M.  My solution is fast but it is overly customized and reinventing the proverbial wheel once I discovered IM.

Comment: The `-scale` is actually completely independent of the `-statistic`, you can see that in my second example. The `-statistic` widens any black pixel to a width of 200 before the `-scale`.

Comment: Yes, yes, now I know that trying to make `-scale` use the `minimum` algorithm to do its job was a dead end, but before your answer I did not even know that `-statistic minimum` was an option.

Comment: How does the performance of `-morphology` compare with `-statistic minimum` ? See the suggestion from fmw42.

Comment: I have not timed it but I imagine `-morphology erode rectangle 200x1` would run in a similar time. Note that my suggestion is somewhat different from Fred's comment (@fmw42). I am suggesting you extend any black pixels horizontally to become more significant, whereas Fred was suggesting you fill any small gaps in your 1 pixel wide column. Fred's will be faster because it is only a 1x5 structuring element, but it relies on any rows with small numbers of black pixels being sandwiched between rows with larger numbers of black pixels. Mine will hopefully work for a solitary black pixel anywhere.

Comment: Yes, not ignoring a solitary black pixel is what I call "reliability" of the algorithm.  BTW: Would specifying `-type bilevel` speed up your algorithm at any stage ?

Comment: Assuming 8bpp and 99% thresholding, wouldn't `minimum "%[fx:int(w/99)]x1"` be optimal since any row averaged to be brighter than 1% will be thresholded to white anyway. Also, can the thresholding be improved to 1-1/256 or 99.6% leading to `minimum "%[fx:int(w/255)]x1"`?

Comment: By the way, `-fill black +opaque white` is probably more reliable than the initial `-threshold` you had.